# Integrating changes in the kernel using Yocto using patches

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

If you want to modify the linux kernel such that it excludes certain modules, you usually go to `/kernel/msm-4.9/arch/arm/configs/vendor/<machine-name>_defconfig`, which has a bunch of Kconfig symbols, and the ones I want to exclude are commented out, as shown below.

```
CONFIG_PPP=y
#CONFIG_PPPOL2TP=y
CONFIG_PPP_ASYNC=y
```

Then I build the linux image by running `bitbake virtual/kernel` which should ideally have my changes integrated, but when I boot the image, I still see some of the logs of the commented module showing up.

I checked [yocto documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-the-patch) and looks like they create a patch of the file they want to modify, and then append that modified file in the `.bbappend` file like:

```
 FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

 SRC_URI += "file://0001-calibrate-Add-printk-example.patch"
```

So in my case, if I were to modify `/kernel/msm-4.9/arch/arm/configs/vendor/<machine-name>_defconfig`, I would:

- create a copy of this original file
- paste it into `poky/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux-msm/files`
- rename it
- include this file in the .bbappend (as shown above)

But how will the above patch override the original `/kernel/msm-4.9/arch/arm/configs/vendor/<machine-name>_defconfig` that I planned on modifying by this approach?

Comment: First of all, proper disabling the option would be `# CONFIG_PPPOL2TP is not set` (exactly how I wrote, including all spaces, etc). What you did with your commenting is switching to whatever is default.

Comment: That shouldn't matter I reckon since `#` just refers to a comment and anything followed by # is irrelevant, no? Also, the `.config` file that gets generated in the `poky` does have `# CONFIG_PPPOL2TP is not set` so I guess the build system looks into what's been commented out in the respective `defconfig` files and ensures it's not included in the kernel image. Also, running `rebake virtual/kernel` did the trick but i'm still unsure how to go about using a patch to achieve a similar task...

Comment: No. Build system doesn’t look into comments, it simply ignores them. And then **default** is applied, whatever it is. In you particular case it means disable in many others it maybe something different. There are three states in the configuration: a) enabled (as “y” or “m”), b) disabled (as “# ... is not set”, or c) ignored as comment or unparsable garbage (means default on this particular configuration).

Comment: If using `#` ignores them, why would adding `is not set` be any useful instead of just commenting it out by using `#`?

Comment: Read my comments again. If something is it clear, read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, sources modifications are done with help of patches in Yocto. Answering your question

> But how will the above patch override the original /kernel/msm-4.9/arch/arm/configs/vendor/_defconfig that I planned on modifying by this approach?

**it is done automagically**:)

That is, build system (*bitbake*) automatically detects files with extension `.patch` among `SRC_URI` content, copies those files from `meta-layer` directory to build directory somewhere under `build/tmp/work/...` and automatically applies thous patches on source code (sources directory is defined by `S` variable in recipe).

But there are some recommendations about other stuff in your question. Some concepts here, skip it to *the right way is* or even *fast way* below if bored))

One of the main ideas behind Yocto is **reproducible and extensible builds**. That means, that all metadata is split into different repositories (that is `layers`), that are maintained by different teams. Basically teams do not have access to each others repos and none has access to some external project (`kernel` in your case) source code. Of cource, one may create `git-fork`s of all this, but this is way more complicated than writing metadata. That's why Yocto was created - to take external metadata (ex., `poky` layer), source code ('kernel') and make it work only by writing your one metadata (your own layer), with no any `git-fork`s.

So, adding your patch and `.bbappend` to `poky` layer make no sense, because you wouldn't be able to commit `poky` layer and distribute this to your customers - `poky` layer belongs not to you) You may create `git-fork` however, but that complicates the process of distribution.

That's why **the right way is**:

- create your own [BSP-layer](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bsp-guide/bsp.html?highlight=create%20layer)
- create `.bbappend` in your layer
- add patch to the kernel in your layer (actually the right way is to [use .scc files](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/advanced.html), put patch also will go)

This shall make your build

- reproducible - rerunning kernel compilation, or even fresh clone of Yocto with your BSP-layer, would be able to produce the same kernel
- distributable (extensible) - customers need only your BSP-layer, other Yocto stuff may be found on internet

And finally, the **fast way**. If you don't need all this *reproducible and extensible* but just build some stuff for your home-project and send Yocto to trash, hack the build like this:

1. clean all kernel-stuff you have `bitbake -c cleansstate virtual/kernel`
2. get kernel sources (clone and patch) `bitbake -c patch virtual/kernel`
3. handle manually everything you need in kernel sources, found somewhere on working stuff like `<TOPDIR>/build/tmp/work/<machine-name>-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/<version>/git`
4. build the kernel `bitbake -c package virtual/kernel` (cloning and patching would be skipped, as bitbake remembers this tasks are done; kernel build artifacts wouldn't be removed, because task `rm_work` goes after `package`, and kernel stuff actually is never removed)

But in this case, if this kernel stuff is removed, or breaks somehow, you'll have to walk through this algorithm again (remember - not reproducible).

To easy rebuild the kernel manually (not through bitbake) you can run script `<TOPDIR>/build/tmp/work/<machine-name>-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/<version>/temp/run.do_compile`

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I was midway through when I looked up about not creating a metalayer under poky but the example I linked in the description does create a layer inside poky. If not poky, where should the metalayer be created? the `meta-bsp` layer in my case is located inside `poky`

Comment: hm... maybe i misunderstood you, sorry than) [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#create-a-layer-for-your-changes) it is said to create you own layer. If you walked through this point, than everything is along the guidelines.

Comment: Yep, sorry, i have a little more customized Yocto working directory (in your case it names `poky`, in my case directory tree looks another way), so i misunderstood you. Looks like you are doing all the right way!)) Your `meta-bsp` must be your directory with your custom layer. Also according to your link, you may be using old version (2.2.1). Latest version of Yocto is 3.2.1, [check it out](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/common.html#using-traditional-kernel-development-to-patch-the-kernel).

Comment: hm, so we are still modifying the original file, and then creating/adding a patch to the bbappend file which tells Yocto to include our change. I was imagining the idea would be more like creating a new file (copy of the original) and modifying that so we can always go back to the older revisions, no?

Comment: or maybe I'm missing out on the concepts of patches. You could just modify the original file, and rebuild the image without having to create a patch and all that good stuff that the yocto documentation talks about...

Comment: Well, yes, finally we create patch and modify file with help of this patch. The way you actually create patch doesn't matter - you can `git-clone` sources manually in some separate folder and create patch there. Or you can just download patch from somewhere. Try to open the patch - it's just text diff, nothing more. And if you want to roll back the older revisions, just disable the patch (exclude patch file from `SRC_URI` for example).

Comment: Also you may try to thing about this like as optimization - instead of holding two versions of file (original and modified one), you have the original and some modification, that should be applied to the original to create modified one. Pretty similar to `git`, but `git` is much more complicated tool.